# Humans captured by aliens, dissected and turned into AIs

Tags: story-identification, artificial-intelligence, mind-uploading

Details I remember from the book for sure:

- Two of the characters were captured by an alien race. They were dissected by the aliens.
- One was turned into an AI to trick the humans of it being peaceful. He didn't do as told and the alien deleted him as he warned the humans.
- Humans have mastered cloning and use it as a form of immortality.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. Please take a look at the check lists in [this thread](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question), and then [edit] your question to include any more details that you can think to add. The more info you can provide about the book (the approximate year in which you read it, for example), the better the odds that someone can ID this for you. :-)

Comment: Sounds vaguely like something by Peter F. Hamilton - the Commonwealth Saga has immortality by cloning, and an alien that captures two of the crew of an investigating spaceship. I will see if I can dig out the book and check if it's a match.

Comment: @Eiki Check Pandora's Star.  Dr. Dudley Bose was one of two humans captured by the Primes.  He was uploaded.  It's a likely fit.

Comment: @Adriot Dyson spheres and two warring civilizations in a binary star system?

Comment: I do t remember about waring systems... But i vividly remember some details.. Like how he was playing along before telling the humans it was a danger... That he had been reborn as a clone but because of the fact his "chip" wasn't recovered that he was cloned with none of his memories that had not been backed up. And also he had fallen in love with the other human... But those memories were not in the clone

Comment: I think this is Pandora's Star.  If correct, @EikiPierstorff commented first and should have the credit.

Comment: This sounds a smidge like the MO of the Cybermen of Doctor Who… not sure if they've made it into novel form.

Comment: I agree with @eik.  This definitely has similarities to the Commonwealth Saga.  The following StackExchange entry references the Bose memories being co-opted by the alien Prime.   https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/173403/why-didnt-the-primes-take-over-the-commonwealth/204009#204009

Comment: I think the starflyer also captures humans. It would be great if somebody with an electronic copy would make this an answer - the Commonwealth saga is such a huge tome that is almost impossible to find anything specific just by thumbing through it.

Answer (score 10):

@EikePierstorff should get credit for this answer.

I found the section of [Pandora's Star](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/45252.Pandora_s_Star) where the alien destroys the uploaded personality of astronomer Dr. Dudley Bose. Emmanuelle Verbeke was the name of the other human captured.

From page 723:

> “Where’s Emmanuelle, Dudley? Is she there with you?”
>
> “No, she’s back on the homeworld DEAD RUN YOU DUMB FUCK RUN THEY
> KILLED US THEY’LL KILL ALL OF US IT’S INHUMAN RUN YOU MOTHERFU—”
>
> MorningLightMountain wanted to scream in pure fury as the betraying
> corruption burned through its consciousness. Its mind crushed the Bose
> memories as they blossomed out of the immotile brain where they had
> been stored, pummeling them back under control. Crushing them.
> Eradicating them from existence.

Downloading a copy of a person's mind into a new clone body is known as 're-lifing'.

From page 748:

> After enduring horrors which we cannot begin to imagine, Dr. Dudley
> Bose sacrificed whatever was left of himself to warn us of the Primes’
> true intent. Expressing the debt of gratitude which every human alive
> today owes to this great man, and his shipmate Emmanuelle Verbeke,
> goes beyond words. I am informed that their re-life procedure goes
> well, and we can only give thanks to whatever gods we believe in that
> they will soon rejoin our society so we may embrace them with the
> welcome they so richly deserve.

More information can be found [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commonwealth_Saga#Longevity).

Now I want to read all the Commonwealth stories again, in order.

Comment: "Now I want to read all the Commonwealth stories again, in order." I hope you're young and vigorous...People past fifty probably don't have enough lifespan ahead of them to read them all again...